# Rodando Webservice Java fora do eclipse com Maven

Tags: java, web-service, maven

Olá,
Tenho um projeto de webservice que no meu computador roda normalmente, utilizando o eclipse e tomcat. E agora quero transportar esse projeto para um servidor e que ele rode apenas com o Tomcat.
Ai surge também uma duvida: O Tomcat e projeto puxariam as pendencias do Maven ?

Obs: Maven está configurado no servidor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, o .war (pacote gerado pelo jdk) possui todos os artefatos referenciados no maven, ou seja, seria somente realizar o deploy desse pacote no tomcat do servidor. Não precisaria do maven no servidor.

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/126885)

Comment: @Renan , editei a resposta. Sou novo dando respostas, se ainda assim ela não responder a pergunta é porque não entendi e faço a remoção. Valeu!

Comment: Não precisa remover, e agora você tem meu voto.

Comment: Estarei testando hoje a noite, tenho que reinstalar o Eclipse no PC e testarei!